# Render Jekyll collection metadata to each output document using layout template

Tags: collections, metadata, jekyll

Given a custom Jekyll collection in a folder `_stuff`, where each document has some metadata, how do I render that metadata using a layout template to an output document? I suspect I need a plugin to do any more than iterating over a collection. E.g. in `_config.yml`:

```
collections:
  stuff:
    output: true
    permalink: /stuff/:path
```

In collection item, e.g. `_stuff/thing1.md`:

```
---
title: Thing 1
some_data: 123
layout: stuff-detail
---
```

Using layout, `stuff-detail.liquid`:

```
---
....
---

<div>Stuff Item Data: {{ page.some_data }} (doesn't work)</div>
```

Comment: It should work that way, do you have a public repo? or please post the full layout code

Answer (score 1):

In your `stuff-detail.liquid` file you'll need double brackets around your liquid call: `{{ page.some_data }}`

Comment: Updated question. Sorry, I did try this and it doesn't work - my question text was wrong.

Comment: I've created a repo with the same details as above: https://github.com/bradonomics/jekyll-collection-example. It's working fine for me. If you have a working repo that is public, maybe you could post it.

Comment: Brad: awesome stuff. Confirmed working - gonna try figure out why mine isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code on your layout `stuff-detail.liquid`:

```
<div>Stuff Item Data: {{ page.output }}</div>
```

See how it works as explained [*here*](https://gist.github.com/chetabahana/25572d8d8fc7cdc25f4e9a3012db9287).